# What is the difference between azure-eventhubs and spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-kafka, amqp, azure-eventhub

My requirement is a simple pub-sub using Azure Events Hub using Spring.

Upon checking the documentation, I've found 2 articles which demonstrate the integration. [One uses azure-eventhubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send) library and [the other uses spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub)

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First be careful that you where referring to an old version of the article to use Azure Event Hubs in Java, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-java-send-v2) is the most recent one.

In the first one the article shows you how to use the Java SDK for Event Hubs in a "classic" java application.

The second article explain how to use Event Hubs in a Spring Boot Java application (Spring Boot is an open-source framework maintained by Pivotal).

Answer (score 2):

Well,  I look at it this way.   I'd say there are 3-4 ways to do it.  You can connect to Eventhubs either as Kafka/9093 or AMQP/5671.   I think it is sad that there isn't a page anywhere that gives advice on this:

1. First, the most basic: `azure-messaging-eventhubs` lib.  I would put
   `azure-core` and `azure-core-amqp`  as being related.    You could use `azure-core` to connect for a health check for example: `EventHubClient.createFromConnectionStringSync(connectionString, Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor());` .   This method gives you the most flexibility but you will write a little more code and handle configuration properties on your own.
2. Then, you might see `azure-spring-cloud-starter-eventhubs` , which has a kafka variant called `spring-cloud-starter-azure-eventhubs-kafka`.    The spring lib `azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-eventhubs`  might be related to this.  This lib expects a particular `application.properties` config (not the same as #3).   One thing I like about this one is that it lazy-loads and your spring-boot service will start  even when lib cannot connect, and problem will show in health check.
3. Then, there is this wrapper around what we have in `#1`&`#2`,  `spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder`.   This lib has its own particular `application.properties` config (not the same as `#2`).   This has a health check built-in but I couldn't get it to work.   With this one, your service will not start if it can't make a connection to configure the Beans.
4. Maybe you don't want to use one of the above wrapper libs.  In that case, you could just use basic `spring-kafka` also.  I made an example: https://github.com/djangofan/kafka-on-azure